# Javascript XML Read Error on Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

It works for Firefox but not for Chrome and IE.

I try it on local.
I get error on httpObj.send( null ); line.

How can i handle this problem ?

**HTML File**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>XML READ</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
//---
        function GetXml() {

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

                var httpObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {

                var httpObj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            httpObj.open("GET", "notification.xml", false);

        // Error Starts Here    
            httpObj.send( null );

            var xmlDocument = httpObj.responseXML;

            var xmlEl = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("haber");

  //--          
            for (i = 0; i < xmlEl.length; i++) {


                for (j = 0; j < xmlEl[i].childNodes.length; j++) {

                    if (xmlEl[i].childNodes[j].nodeType != 1) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    alert(xmlEl[i].childNodes[j].firstChild.nodeValue);
                }


            }



        }


    </script>
</head>
<body onload="GetXml()">
</body>
</html>
```

**XML File**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <notifications>

        <notification id="001">
            <name>First</name>
        </notification>

        <notification id="002">
            <name>Second</name>

        </notification>

    </notifications>
```

Comment: Why are passing null in 'send' function??

Comment: i tried without null first it also doesnt work, then i see some examples that uses null to handle this problem but it seems not useful for me.

Comment: Is that one XML file, or two?  If it's a single file, I would think it should have a root element.

Comment: `xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("haber");` 

where is this haber element in your xml?

I assume it's just incompleteness so could you please provide some more of the xml data?

Comment: sorry  it should be : xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("notification");  but i paste old version of it, its not the real problem

Comment: @LazyMonkey root elements didnt show when i paste my xml file,  now it's edited by moderator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works in chrome and IE if you replace

`xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("haber");`

with

`xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("notification");`

Also when you say `I try it on local` make sure that it is hosted in a server e.g. apache and the server is running

**Old comment:**
check this link about browser combatibility and correct ajax call

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlfile.asp

Comment: well it worked for me. you should also get the cd_catalog.xml from that link and place it in the same folder with your test.html page (containing the html from the tryit yourself link. I also assume you place these2 files in a server not just double click from desktop or else it will not work

Comment: all files ok but i dont try them on server, i just copy on desktop,  i will try on server and back.

Comment: it works on server, thankyou so much. Why it doesnt work on desktop btw?

Comment: ajax calls are making a request to the server. If no server is running then no response will be recieved